# Adding a Switch

Tags: wiring

I would like to add a switch to an exhaust fan in my workshop. The fan would also have a thermostat to control the temperature. How would I wire the switch to the thermostat and then to the fan? I want to add the switch, just in case I need to turn it off.

Comment: A few more details please. Where are you in the world, what type of fan, Voltage, size, power requirements, current wiring, location of the fan and the t-stadt, where do you wish to have the switch located? Pics would help too.

Comment: How is the exhaust fan currently controlled?